# On focus, how to place the caret after the last character in an already populated field in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

On focus, how to place the caret after the last character  in an already populated field in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textareaname.scrollTop = textareaname.scrollHeight;
```

Works for textareas

Nevermind, try this: http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/

Comment: I appreciate your help, `document.getElementById("field").scrollTop = document.getElementById("field").scrollHeight;` seems to not be working.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 makes it easy, with [.selectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [.selectionEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It looks like in prior versions you'll need to call [.createTextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then manipulate the returned object with .move, .moveStart, .moveEnd, and [.movePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Correct, although you're over-complicating what you need to do in IE.

Comment: Perhaps - I get sad every time I have to re-learn it and wade through the MSDN documents.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work in all major browsers, including IE 5-9. IE 9 will support the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of text inputs, bringing it into line with all the other browsers.

```
function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to reset content of input element, like this:

```
var element_content = false;    
element = document.getElemetById('xyz');
//put focus on element and remember current content
element.focus();
element_content = element.value; 
//now, clear content of element
element.value='';
//and return stored content back to the element, browser moves cursor to the end itself ;) 
element.value=element_content;
```